# Using or Avoiding CommandBuilder in ADO.NET

Tags: sql, ado.net, sqlcommandbuilder

Is it advisable to use CommandBuilder or should one manually create the InsertCommand, DeleteCommand and UpdateCommand for SqlDataAdapter?

The obvious advantage to using CommandBuilder is less developer time, the disadvantage being more run time. Besides these factors, is there anything else one must keep in mind while using/avoiding CommandBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Using raw ADO.NET like `SqlCommandBuilder`, `SqlDataAdapter` and so forth typically involves a lot of boilerplate code that can be avoided.

Most modern line of business applications these days use some form of ORM (object relational mapper) that provide a nice set of wrappers which under the covers use the best practice for using raw ADO.NET.

Some of the more popular ORMs are: -

- NHibernate
- Entity Framework
- Linq2Sql
- [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)
- [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)

Using an ORM provides many useful features like simplicity, flexibility, lazy-loading, injection safe queries, POCO support, etc.

If you still have a strong desire to use ADO.NET over an ORM I would suggest obtaining the code for [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) or [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) and coying from the some of the best coding you are likely to find.